# Bad Persian/Arabic font in WhatsApp web

Tags: 20.04, firefox, fonts, whatsapp

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.01 L.T.S and after a while installing it, WhatsApp web Persian fonts changed to something really annoying, and the problem is I don't know whether its from Ubuntu, or WhatsApp web because I tried with another browser but nothing changed.

Can anybody help me change this bad font to another better Persian/Arabic font? Look at the picture:

[image: it is horrible!]

When I use `locale` command, the output is:

```
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=
```

Comment: It may be the result of [this discourse thread](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/request-better-arabic-font-for-ubuntu-20-04/14573). Please feel free to provide your input there.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i don't understand this page, could you explain more...?

Comment: We did change the default font for Arabic for users with an Arabic locale. Can you please edit your question and show us the output from this terminal command: `locale`

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be due to  **Microsoft TrueType core fonts**
I resolved the issue by Uninstalling it

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Persian Locale, to do that run `sudo apt-get install language-pack-fa` command, this will fix not only WhatsApp Web but so many other things in your system..., if your having this issue for any other languages, you must replace ***-fa*** with **your own language locale code** *in above command*. you can find your language code in this link: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/localization-guide/appendix-locale-codes.64474/